# Why can't I access a returned function with the dot syntax

Tags: javascript, closures

I though that once createFunction runs I'll have access to the inner function.

```
function createFunction() {
  function printHello() {
    return console.log("hello");
  }
  return printHello;
}

// Both of these return undefined
createFunction(printHello());
createFunction.printHello();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: No, you don't have access to local variables inside a function, ever. You can of course do things with the *value* that the function returns (which happens to be the `printHello` function), and then assign that value to your own variable or call it or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Proper syntax is:

```
createFunction()();
```

... or, a bit more wordy:

```
const returnedFunction = createFunction();
returnedFunction();
```

... as `printHello` name makes any sense only within `createFunction`, but its value is actually *returned* by that function. And yes, it's perfectly ok to place any number of `()` in sequence you want.

As a sidenote, returning the result of `console.log('hello')` makes little sense: logging itself is a side effect, no need to check its result.

Answer (score 1):

> I though that once createFunction runs I'll have access to the inner function.

No, you cannot access a variable that is inside of a function outside of it. If you call a function those variables exist, but you cannot access them. However if a value gets `return`ed, you can work with the function call as if it would be that expression. In your case you return the function so you can access it as:

```
 var print = createFunction();
 print();
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
 createFunction()();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code createFunction returns another function, so to execute inner function you must call inner function by appending () after return value of createFunction i.e createFunction()();

createFunction() give printHello = function definition
 
createFunction() **()** same as printHello**()**

Also if we simplify your code we can re-write as

```js
function printHello() {
     console.log("hello");
 };
function createFunction() {
  return printHello;
};
console.log("return value of: createFunction()");
console.log(createFunction());

console.log("return value of: createFunction() () --> printHello()");
createFunction()();
```